# How to randomly select elements of array for changing button text?

Tags: java, arrays, select, button, random

I have almost managed to get my program working, but there is still one last bit I am having trouble with. I do not believe anybody has asked this question yet, because I am trying to select a JButton according to an array value which has been randomly selected. I generated one hundred JButtons on a grid, and I want to randomly select twenty for changing their text. Problem is, the text is not changing! So I am thinking I have not really selected any buttons. My problem code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Random randomRow = new Random(10);
    Random randomColumn = new Random(10);
    if (button == buttons[randomRow.nextInt(10)+1][randomColumn.nextInt(10)+1])
    {
        button.setText("treasure");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your attempt at selecting 20 buttons is not correct.

Comment: You might want to initialise your Random outside the for loop, as random is not actually really random. and it seems to be a duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt at selecting exactly 20 buttons randomly is incorrect.

You have a multidimensional array in Java containing 100 JButtons, in a 10x10 grid like so:

```
buttons = [
    [JButton0, JButton1, ..., JButton9],
    ...
    [JButton89, JButton90, ..., JButton99]
]
```

And you want to select 20 buttons randomly. But in the code you provided, you are iterating over all the buttons, and inside the loop you are generating a random number and checking if this iteration matches the random number.

This is wrong, you should randomly select 20 unique indexes, and individually change the buttons at those random indexes.

---

**Here's some code that will will selected 20 buttons by random from a multidimensional array.**

```
JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[10][10]; // Array of 100 JButtons
int totalButtons = 0;                      // Length of total buttons
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) { // Count the length of total buttons
    if (i == 0) {
        totalButtons = buttons[i].length;
    } else {
        totalButtons += buttons[i].length;
    }
}
int[] randomIndex = new int[20];            // 20 random button indexes

// Fill random indexes
Random random = new Random();                         // Generate a random
for (int i = 0; i < randomIndex.length; ++i) {        // Iterate over randomIndex array
    int randomInt = random.nextInt(totalButtons);     // Get a random integer from the random

    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {                     // Iterate over randomIndex array but no further than i
        if (randomInt == randomIndex[j]) {            // Check if random index already exists
            randomInt = random.nextInt(totalButtons); // If random index already exists, select a different index
            --j;                                      // Do not iterate, check same index again
        }
    }

    randomIndex[i] = randomInt; // Set random index
}

// Change button texts
for (int i : randomIndex) {                // Iterate over random indexes
    int row = i / 10;                      // Get row from index
    int col = i % 10;                      // Get column from index

    buttons[row][col].setText("treasure"); // Modify randomly selected button
}
```

Comment: I'm not super experienced in Java, but I'll work on adding some example code for you to use.

Comment: Holy moly, that is a serious block of code, thank you very much!

Comment: @Orion thats great! If it's solved, please accept an answer to mark your question as solved :)